# Is this function differentiable $f(x)= \frac{e^{-|x|}}{\max (e^{x},e^{-x})}$?

Tags: continuity

Consider the function
 $$f(x)= \frac{e^{-|x|}}{\max (e^{x},e^{-x})}$$

Is this function differentiable at every point?
My progress - 
I was able to split the function in two parts

For 
$$x>0, f(x) = e^{-2x}$$

For

$$ x<0, f(x) = e^{2x}$$
Then I drew the graph and found one  " pointy point" on which the function has two tangents thus I thought it is not differentiable at just one point but turns out the answer is the function is not differentiable anywhere. can you help me?

Comment: The function is just $f(x) = e^{-2|x|}$ which is differentiable everywhere except at $x=0$.

Comment: Is the answer from a course book? Seems strange to me.

Comment: No it's a question booklet for a competitive exam

Answer (score 2):

Then $f(x)=e^{-2x}. x>0; f(x)=e^{2x}, x<0, f(0)=1$
So this function is continuous but not differentiable at $x=0$ because at this
point right derivative is $-2$ and the left derivative is $2$, which are finite but un-equal.